# How to get preview of video in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, youtube, tinymce, wysiwyg, preview

I'm using tinyMCE as WYSIWYG editor on my blog. Unfortunately when I add video (from youtube or vimeo) it's not visible in editor window (I can only see the code when viewing it in HTML mode). Is there a way to generate preview or even better to have the ability to play video in the editor window ?

Answer (score 6):

No straight-forward solution available, but I think the question deserves a better answer than the one above.

In TinyMCE before version 3.4b3, media that was embedded as an iframe would play in the WYSIWYG mode. Yes, a WYSIWYG editor can do this (as opposed to what is claimed in the answer above).

In version 3.4b3 the media plugin was changed to match a change in YouTube's embed code.

From 3.4b3 and onward, the media plugin replaces the iframe with a yellow box having the same size of the media it's representing. The original iframe attributes are encapsulated as JSON and preserved in a special tag during editing. Later When the text is saved out, the attributes are restored into the original iframe.

Searching on this or similar topics returns several suggestions to use valid_elements or extended_valid_elements. Those settings will affect how HTML elements are treated. They cannot be used to enable media preview in the WYSIWYG mode.

This seems to be by design, as is indicated by [how the TinyMCE CTO reasons about media vs placeholders here](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=60960#p60960). And he also demonstrates the acceptable operation of the media plugin [in this screencast](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=61376#p61376) where no preview is displayed after switching to the preview mode.

I'm still looking for a good solution for this using the standard product. As an alternative, a custom version of the media plugin could be written with domain white-listing added to tell it to leave iframes from those domains untouched so they will display also in WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, TinyMCE (or basically any WYSIWYGs) can't do that.

Comment: why not ? inside the editor's iframe it's just normal html document.

Comment: No.  Instead this question wouldn't exist.  They may use some cheats which remove “unsafe” elements.

Answer (score 0):

[media_live_embeds](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/media/)

When you enable this option users will see a live preview of embedded video content within the editable area, rather than a placeholder image. This means that users can play a video clip, such as YouTube, within the editor.